# "No gradients provided for any variable" when trying to fit Keras Sequential

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to create and train a Sequential model like so:

```
def model(training: Dataset, validation: Dataset):
    model = Sequential(layers=[Embedding(input_dim=1001, output_dim=16), Dropout(0.2), GlobalAveragePooling1D(), Dropout(0.2), Dense(1)])
    model.compile(loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer='adam', metrics=BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0))
    model.fit(x=training, validation_data=validation, epochs=10)
```

When I run it, I get the following error the `model.fit` line:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['embedding/embeddings:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0'].
```

I've come across some answers talking about the use of optimizers, but how would that apply to `Sequential` rather than `Model`? Is there something else that I'm missing?

Edit: The result of `print(training)`:

```
<MapDataset shapes: ((None, 250), (None,)), types: (tf.int64, tf.int32)>
```

Edit: A script that will reproduce the error using IMDB sample data

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow import data
from keras.layers import TextVectorization
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import BinaryAccuracy, BinaryCrossentropy
import os


def split_dataset(dataset: data.Dataset):
    record_count = len(list(dataset))
    training_count = int((70 / 100) * record_count)
    validation_count = int((15 / 100) * record_count)

    raw_train_ds = dataset.take(training_count)
    raw_val_ds = dataset.skip(training_count).take(validation_count)
    raw_test_ds = dataset.skip(training_count + validation_count)

    return {"train": raw_train_ds, "test": raw_test_ds, "validate": raw_val_ds}


def clean(text, label):
    return tf.strings.unicode_transcode(text, "US ASCII", "UTF-8")


def vectorize_dataset(dataset: data.Dataset):
    return dataset.map(vectorize_text)


def vectorize_text(text, label):
    text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)
    return vectorize_layer(text), label


url = "https://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz"
dataset_tar = tf.keras.utils.get_file("aclImdb_v1", url,
                                    untar=True, cache_dir='.',
                                    cache_subdir='')
dataset_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset_tar), 'aclImdb')

batch_size = 32
seed = 42
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'aclImdb/train',
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=seed)

split_data = split_dataset(dataset)
raw_train = split_data['train']
raw_val = split_data['validate']
raw_test = split_data['test']

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000, output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=250, ngrams=1)
cleaned_text = raw_train.map(clean)
vectorize_layer.adapt(cleaned_text)

train = vectorize_dataset(raw_train)
test = vectorize_dataset(raw_test)
validate = vectorize_dataset(raw_val)


def model(training, validation):
    sequential_model = Sequential(
        layers=[Embedding(input_dim=1001, output_dim=16), Dropout(0.2), GlobalAveragePooling1D(), Dropout(0.2),
                Dense(1)])
    sequential_model.compile(loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer='adam', metrics=BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0))
    sequential_model.fit(x=training, validation_data=validation, epochs=10)


model(train, validate)
```

Comment: What contains your `training` variable? In your example, you're trying to do supervised learning without ground truth, so there's no loss to compute, an so  no gradients.

Comment: Honestly, I'm very new to this, so I'm not entirely sure what it is you're asking for here. Its a Dataset, containing text records

Comment: Do you have the corresponding labels in your `tf.data.Dataset`? I.e, is each element of your dataset a pair `(sample, label)` ?

Comment: It's a `MapDataset` with two `element_specs` which correspond to the labels

Comment: You are using a metric for loss function. Look at the imports, BinaryCrossentropy is imported from metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BinaryCrossentropy` is imported from `tf.keras.metrics` hence gradients could not be computed.

Correct import should have been `from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy`.

Comment: `tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy` uses `tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy` under the hood.

Comment: I meant the import in the question actually.

Comment: The loss function is used to optimize your model. This is the function that will get minimized by the optimizer. A metric is used to judge the performance of your model. This is only for you to look at and has nothing to do with the optimization process

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is occurring at below line:

```
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000, output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=250, ngrams=1)
```

The `max_tokens` in the TextVectorization layer corresponds to the `total number of unique words` in the vocabulary.

`Embedding Layer: The Embedding layer can be understood as a lookup table that maps from integer indices (which stand for specific words) to dense vectors (their embeddings)` .

In your code, the `Embedding dimensions` are `(1001,16)` that means you are only accomodating the integers that map the specific words in a range of 1001, any indices that forms a (row, column) pair, which corresponds to a value greater than 1001 are not taken care off. Therefore, the ValueError.

I changed the `TextVectorization(max_tokens=5000)` and also `Embedding(5000, 16)`, and ran your code.

What I got is shown below:

```
def model(training, validation):
   model = keras.Sequential(
    [
     layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16),
     layers.Dropout(0.2),
     layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
     layers.Dropout(0.2),
     layers.Dense(1),
     ]
     )
   model.compile(
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0)
              )
model.fit(x=training, validation_data=validation, epochs=10)
return model

Output:
Epoch 1/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.6797 - binary_accuracy: 0.6455 - val_loss: 0.6539 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7554
Epoch 2/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.6109 - binary_accuracy: 0.7625 - val_loss: 0.5700 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.7880
Epoch 3/10 437/437 [==============================] - 9s 22ms/step - loss: 0.5263 - binary_accuracy: 0.8098 - val_loss: 0.4931 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8233
Epoch 4/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.4580 - binary_accuracy: 0.8368 - val_loss: 0.4373 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8448
Epoch 5/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.4072 - binary_accuracy: 0.8560 - val_loss: 0.4003 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8522
Epoch 6/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3717 - binary_accuracy: 0.8641 - val_loss: 0.3733 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8589
Epoch 7/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3451 - binary_accuracy: 0.8728 - val_loss: 0.3528 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8582
Epoch 8/10 437/437 [==============================] - 9s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3220 - binary_accuracy: 0.8806 - val_loss: 0.3345 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8673
Epoch 9/10 437/437 [==============================] - 9s 22ms/step - loss: 0.3048 - binary_accuracy: 0.8868 - val_loss: 0.3287 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8673
Epoch 10/10 437/437 [==============================] - 10s 22ms/step - loss: 0.2891 - binary_accuracy: 0.8929 - val_loss: 0.3222 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8679
```

Comment: So, is your issue solved????you started a bounty on it...are you gonna award or is it just a bummer??